# Save Audit.WebApi logs to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.2, audit.net

I am using Audit.WepApi ([found here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WebApi/README.md)) with my .Net Core 2.2 application which is a Web API. I managed to configure it on my controllers using the default options. It is great for logging API calls which should hopefully add to the security aspect

However, I cannot seem to find any information about saving the logs to a SQL database. Or is there any program to make better sense of the .json files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#storage-providers) you can find the documentation index for the different data providers you can use to store the audit events.

For example you can reference the package [`Audit.Net.SqlServer`](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.SqlServer/README.md) and configure the provider via `.UseSqlServer` extension:

```
using Audit.Core;

Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseSqlServer(_ => _
        .ConnectionString("data source=...")
        .TableName("Event")
        .IdColumnName("EventId")
        .JsonColumnName("Data"));
```

You can also create your own data provider. Check the documentation [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers), for example:

```
public class MyCustomDataProvider : AuditDataProvider
{
    public override object InsertEvent(AuditEvent auditEvent)
    {
        var json = auditEvent.ToJson();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: where we need to setup the providers, which file?

Comment: Depends on your project type, but it should be at the initialization of your application (before any audit takes place). For ASP.NET Core it could be on the `Startup` class.